# Откуда берётся None?

Tags: python, парсер

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS


def get_html(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    return r.text


def get_data(html):
    soup = BS(html, 'lxml')
    spans = soup.find('span').text
    print(spans)


def main():
    url = 'https://yandex.ru/pogoda/213'
    print(get_data(get_html(url)))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

на выходе:

```
Прогноз на 10 дней
None
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS


def get_html(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    return r.text


def get_data(html):
    soup = BS(html, 'lxml')
    spans = soup.find('span').text
    return spans


def main():
    url = 'https://yandex.ru/pogoda/213'
    print(get_data(get_html(url)))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Функция get_data по умолчанию возвращала None, я исправил это заменив `print(spans)` на `return spans`